# Default Pages with Theme Install

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I'm building a theme to be my deafult template to all my wp installs, I've managed to sucessfully create a theme options page and I can integrate them a page theme, but for this to work it is required that I create a new page, for instance, "Privacy Policy", set the page theme to my costum page theme that calls theme options, publish the page, modify the theme options in admin area. This works, but this is nto what I'm lookig for,

What I want is a pipeline that goes like, ->install theme->configure theme options-> done

I want to skip the process of creatign a new page and applying the page theme to it, I would like do this "hardcoded", like, a link in the footer to /privacypolicy.php", problem is that it does not work this way, I'm guessing this would be something related to .htaccess, like adding the permanent redirect to the full themplate directory / targetpage.php / and redirect it to something like "blogurl/privacypolicy", is it? the probleme is I know squat about configuring a .htaccess redirect or whateverm what should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea...what if you setup a clean WordPress install using the theme you developed. Add a page and put in the content that you want (Private Policy) and then extract the page entry from the table that WordPress stores it in and convert it into a sql statement which you then execute when your theme is activated. Make sure though that the page does not exist yet. Hope this helps.